# Loading Properties file is giving weird behavior

Tags: java, spring, properties, applicationcontext

Consider this example

```
 public class EmailSender {    
 private Properties emailProperties;
 public Properties getEmailProperties() {
    return emailProperties;
  }

  public void setEmailProperties(Properties emailProperties) {
    this.emailProperties = emailProperties;
  }
```

In `applicationContext.xml` I have something like

```
<bean name="emailSender" class="com.api.email.EmailSender">
    <property name="emailProperties" value="classpath*:email.properties"/>
</bean>
```

When I debug whats get set, I see

[image]

How do I load `Properties` for `emailProperties`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to inject another bean which knows how to resolve Properties. The following worked for me

```
<bean id="emailProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:email.properties"/>
</bean>

<bean name="emailSender" class="com.api.email.EmailSender">
    <property name="emailProperties" ref="emailProperties"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you assign the property file seems incomplete.  I normally use the util functions. Add this to your context xml file namespace:

xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

Then declare your property file:

```
<util:properties
    id="emailProperties"
    location="classpath:/app.properties"/>
```

And set the bean value:

```
<bean name="emailSender" class="com.api.email.EmailSender">
    <property name="emailProperties" ref="emailProperties"/>
</bean>
```

Maybe things have been simplified in Spring 4, but that's how you do it in 3 and earlier. it's a teensy bit shorter than using org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
<context:property-placeholder  location="classpath*:email.properties" />

<bean class="com.test.EmailSender" >
    <property name="prop1" value="${mail.prop1}" />
    <property name="prop2" value="${mail.prop2}" />
</bean>
```

-

```
public class EmailSender {

    private String prop1;
    private String prop2;

    public String getProp1() {
        return prop1;
    }

    public void setProp1(String prop1) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
    }

    public String getProp2() {
        return prop2;
    }

    public void setProp2(String prop2) {
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }
}
```